# Entity Framework Core seed entity problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I try to add a migration for the below entities and i get the error. I've tried everything to get it to work and i feel like i'm missing something obvious. The code is below

"The seed entity for type 'Bug' cannot be added because no value was provided for the required property 'UserId'"

```
public class Bug
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int BugId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Bug>().HasData(
                new Bug()
                {
                    BugId = 1,
                    Title = "TestTitle1",
                    Description = "Test1Description1",
                    DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                    Status = Status.Closed,
                    User = new User() { UserId = 1, UserName = "TestUser1" },
                }
```

I have tried the above as well as looking up shadow keys and seperating Bug and User entitities

Comment: The error message seems to be pretty clearly saying that you need a UserId property on your Bug class. Did you try that? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I tried adding a UserId property to the Bug class and got "The seed entity for type 'Bug' cannot be added because no value was provided for the required property 'UserId1'" so basically a repeat of the previous error message.

Comment: Did you try providing a value for the UserId property when declaring your new Bug instance?

Comment: Yes, i did that in this line of code User = new User() { UserId = 1, UserName = "TestUser1"

Comment: The UserId of the User object is not the same as the UserId of the Bug object. The error is saying you need to set the UserId of the Bug.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

Thanks for all your suggestions. I spent a few hours today messing about with it and below is how i managed to get it to work in case anyone else comes across this error.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Bug> Bugs{ get; set; }
}

public class Bug
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var user1 = new User()
        {
            Id = 1,
            UserName = "TestUsername1"
        };

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasData(user1);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Bug>().HasData(
            new Bug()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Title = "TestTitle1",
                Description = "TestDescription1",
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                Status = Status.Open,
                UserId = 1,
            });
        }
```